# Text Overflowing

Tags: css, reactjs

I have just made this little UI at the top of the screen but would like to know how I can prevent the marked text from overflowing. I have tried the `overflow:hidden property` but that hasn't helped. Any help would be appreciated. The CSS element in question is `ward_caption` which is in the `ward_no.css` file

[image]

ward_no.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import './ward_no.css';
import { IoMdArrowDropdown } from 'react-icons/io';
import { GoTriangleUp } from 'react-icons/go';
import wardData from '../../../json_data/ward.json';

const WardNo = () => {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const [ward, setWard] = useState(null);

    const onSelect = (value) => {
        setWard(value);
        setOpen(!open);
    }

    return (
        <div className="ward_no">
            <div className="ward_caption">Ward No</div>
            <div className="ward_block">
                <div className="ward_dropdown">
                    <div className="ward_box">
                        {ward === null ? "Enter Ward Number" : ward}
                    </div>
                    <div className="ward_dropIcon" onClick={() => setOpen(prev => !prev)}>
                        {open ? <GoTriangleUp size={"25px"} /> : <IoMdArrowDropdown size={"30px"} />}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className={open ? "ward_option" : "ward_option_block"}>
                    {wardData.map((number) => <div className="ward_options" onClick={() => onSelect(number?.wardNo)}>
                        {number.wardNo}
                    </div>
                    )}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default WardNo;
```

ward_no.css

```
.ward_no {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.ward_caption {
    flex: 1;
    font-size: 30px;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.ward_block {
    display: block;
    flex: 3;
}

.ward_dropdown {
    display: flex;
    background-color: white;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 4px 1px gray;
}

.ward_box {
    display: flex;
    /* flex-wrap: nowrap; */
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 4;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: gray;
}

.ward_dropIcon {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 1;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

.ward_option_block {
    display: none;
}

.ward_option {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

This component gets rendered from the `main_screen.jsx` file along with two other components placed side by side.

main_screen.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import './main_screen.css';
// import District from "../widgets/dropdowns/district/district";
import SearchBox from "../widgets/dropdowns/district/search_box";
import WardNo from "../widgets/dropdowns/ward_no/ward_no";
import Category from "../widgets/dropdowns/category/category";

const MainScreen = () => {

    return (
        <div className="mainScreen">
            <div className="filterSearch">
                <div className="disctrictDropdown">
                    <SearchBox></SearchBox>
                </div>
                <div className="wardNoDropdown">       //This is the component
                    <WardNo></WardNo>
                </div>
                <div className="categoryDropdown">
                    <Category></Category>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="searchButton">
                Search
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default MainScreen;
```

main_screen.css

```
.mainScreen, body {
    background-color: white;
}

.mainScreen {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.filterSearch {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.disctrictDropdown {
    flex: 1;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.wardNoDropdown {          //This is the wardNoDropdown component
    flex: 1;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.categoryDropdown {
    flex: 1;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.searchButton {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 150px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: lightskyblue;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 4px 1px gray;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: try `white-space: nowrap` to prevent text from wrapping to a new line.

Comment: The text might go on 2 lines because there is not enough space horizontally. Even a horizontal scroll might appear. From UI point of view try to think out a better layout, for example place the three selects vertically, not horizontally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways, which I know could work:

1. Try to add `flex-direction: column;` attribute to the `display: flex` container
   This way it will make the text with those `input fields` ‚listed‘ underneath each other, which looks (for my preference) better
2. Add `white-space: nowrap;` to your text div